# Getting Updated Value from Application Prefrences when App is running in Background

Tags: iphone, ios

Is there is any way of fetching Updated Application Preferences Value from Application Settings while the Application is still running in the Background?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're really running in the background, you can fetch preferences the same way you would if you were running in the foreground.

But if you're in the background and suspended, as is normal for iOS apps except for those in a few limited categories (like VoIP or music players), then when you're in the background you can't do anything.

Some info on the background state here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html

But in a nutshell the important bit is:  "The app is in the background and executing code. Most apps enter this state briefly on their way to being suspended.".